# Is busticket4.me reliable?

Tags: tickets, online-resources, buses, scams, serbia

I want to buy a bus ticket (from Belgrade to Podgorica) online at https://busticket4.me/. However, I wonder if this site is reliable (maybe it's just a scam, maybe they will take my money and will not sell me a ticket).

Does anybody have any experience with them? Has anybody succeeded to buy a ticket from them?

Comment: The site passes all [scam site smoke tests](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/84025/how-do-i-recognize-a-scam-website).  https://www.facebook.com/www.busticket4.me/ looks real, https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.busticket4&hl=en has 72 reviews with a very high rate. Doesn't mean it's legit but sure as hell looks one.

Comment: They mislead people saying that there are just a few tickets available for tou to rush and buy right aeay. You can buy cheaper at bus station! There are a lot of availability as nobody really want to go to those countries they operate. They are not very supportive with customers. I had a big issue with a bus company and they are saying that they dont have anything to do with it as they only sell tickets. They dont provide complete information and this is crucial when visiting an odd country with other language and rude people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As pointed out by @chx they satisfy the general criteria of a real company.

1. They have an active Facebook page with [recent reviews](https://www.facebook.com/pg/www.busticket4.me/reviews/)
2. Their [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.busticket4&hl=en) has plenty of reviews and was recently updated
3. Their contact page lists a [physical address](https://busticket4.me/MNE/kontakt)
4. Their parent company [is real](http://www.firme-cg.com/cassiopeia/) and the owner looks like a real person (please Google their name by yourself)

Whether or not they're *reliable* is primarily opinion based and is not a good fit for a Q&A format.

Answer (score 10):

I have been in Montenegro recently. This is what I have seen on Podgorica main bus station:
[image: busticket4.me website]
[image: busticket4.me ad]
As we see, the screen with a schedule of buses just displays a busticket4.me website. And there is an ad and a logo of busticket4.me there. Which suggests it is not just a scam.